# Dell XPS 15 7590 Killer wifi 1650 card not recognized in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a new Dell XPS 15 7590 laptop. It has a Killer 1650 wireless adapter. It didn't work on first install, but after installing the right drivers (with some help from the ppl at Killer Networks), and disabling secure boot, I got it to work. It worked on two different wifi networks. Today I took it to the client's office, but wifi doesn't work now. Ubuntu doesn't seem to see a wireless adapter (but it did until yesterday). The bios on the laptop says it has an intel wireless adapter, I'm not sure if that's the Killer card or not. 
I'll replace the Killer card by the card from my old XPS15, but I am curious if I can make the card work. It does seem to me it's a hardware issue, as the card doesn't seem to be shown in the bios properly.

I followed the steps from here to install drivers:
https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/
I did that again this morning.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

    3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
    3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
    RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0905]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
```

What can I do to make wifi work on my new laptop?

Edit:
Wifi now works. I had some help from the ppl at Killer Networks. They added some info to their support site: before installing the drivers as described, make sure you disable secure boot in the bios.

Comment: If you installed a driver without dkms, you need to reinstall it after each kernel upgrade. Please post detail on how you installed drivers.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: I re-followed the procedure that the ppl of Killernetworks suggested, now the card works. It does say it's an Intel, the sticker on the card says Killer 1650. I did try an old tplink usb wifi adapter, which worked. It didn't work last week,

Comment: Post new results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` does the driver in use say iwlwifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot

I found info on this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1835858
Since it is Intel backports it will only support Intel wifi

Comment: The card is not Intel, afaik.

Comment: Your results show that it is made by Intel

Comment: That is what the bios reports. But the card is Killer. Or, that's what I saw. And it did work, the last few days. Until this morning.

Comment: I just downloaded and looked at the source code for this and it does support your device `{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x2723, 0x1654, killer1650x_2ax_cfg)},`

Comment: The Killer wifi site tells me how to install the driver. Unfortunately, every time Ubuntu updates, I have to reinstall the driver.

Comment: That is because the killer wifi site is likely not using a dkms solution.  Dkms will build new modules when a new kernel is installed

Comment: The Killer web site also has this for installing the driver: 

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
Without this, the backport-iwlwifi didn't work for me, installing the hw driver afterwards made it all work.

Answer (score 0):

You can now try and update to 19.10 beta, everything works out of the box.

(except brightness and external screen not waking up after a sleep)

Comment: I updated to 19.10, wifi worked like a charm, until a grub bug in 19.10 bricked my laptop. I am back on 19.04 now.

Comment: Oh that sucks, weird, didn't get that GRUB bug :(
There was a wi-fi bug when uploading a lot, but is being fixed now...